# Dropdown menu moves content

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

My problem is quite simple but i don't know what i've done bad..

Dropdown menu on my site moves content.I've tried a z-index with absolute and relative position but it did not worked.Maybe i've screwed something up but right now i don't know what

Thanks for help and Greets

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
#logo {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
.menu>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  min-height: 130px;
}
#fest {
  margin-left: 280px;
}
#pierwszy {
  clear: both;
}
.element {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.element:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu>#logo>p {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.menu>ul>li>ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}
.menu>ul>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
.menu>ul>li:hover>ul:hover>li:hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: #666;
}
.menu>ul>li>ul>li {
  margin: 10px;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>
    LOREN IPSUM DZIADU !
  </title>
  <meta name="description" content="nananananana moje testy i zabawy" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="moje,nowe,zabawy,strony,html" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="topbar">

    <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="developer.png" width=220px height=90px;>
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu">
      <!--<img src="pan.jpg" alt=" "!-->
      <ul>
        <li class="element"><a href="#">Something</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Something</li>
            <li>Something</li>
            <li>Something</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="element"><a href="#">Something</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Something</li>
            <li>Something</li>
            <li>Something</li>

          </ul>
          <li class="element">Something</li>
          <li class="element">Something</li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
    <br/>
    <br/>

  </div>
  </div>
  <article>
    <img id="fest" src="fest.jpg" width=320px height=350px;>
    </a>
    <p>Proin vel luctus urna, a suscipit lectus. Quisque aliquam sollicitudin feugiat. In et venenatis nisl, at mattis arcu. Quisque dictum posuere dui eu luctus. Quisque dignissim ipsum orci, sed malesuada nibh posuere quis. Vestibulum venenatis hendrerit
      enim a scelerisque. Integer fringilla diam et mauris viverra, eget ornare eros faucibus. Phasellus id ex vitae lacus porta pulvinar.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <p>Mauris urna sapien, molestie quis vulputate et, interdum vitae massa. Suspendisse dolor velit, imperdiet eu bibendum vitae, finibus quis lorem. Morbi ultricies lorem quis dui hendrerit luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Duis scelerisque varius leo. Quisque malesuada tortor id risus posuere, sodales rutrum nunc tristique. Vivamus pulvinar id leo ut fringilla.</p>
  </article>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script>
    src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Not related with your issue, but `<img id="fest" src="fest.jpg"width=320px height=350px;>` should be `<img id="fest" src="fest.jpg" width="320" height="350" />` the height and width are normal attr and they needs quotes, the semicolon is not allowed and don't need the px. The renders works because the browser made a extra work to understand it.

Comment: as well `<script>src="js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>` i am not sure this it is doing the thing that you expected. This line is creating a variable src with the string `"js/bootstrap.min.js"` probably you want  `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your css add this styles to the current ones.

```
.element {
 position: relative;
}
.menu>ul>li>ul {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #555;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The key is the position: absolute; The position absolute don't move other elements. With position absolute you can  positioning any page element exactly where you want it without reserve visual space for it. 
This mind that your element can be on top of other elements. With z-index you can manage the stack of this elements.

The position relative in the parent will help as a referent for the top and left properties.

I highly recommend to you read this article:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Thank You for help :) I've added those lines to my code but right now in menu is only one position,just the first one,three others seems to disappear somehow.

Comment: @Atomix it's probably because you applied the top and left positioning to the same menus, so now they're all stacked on top of each other.